# Install "perf" on Mac

Tags: macos, profiling, osx-mavericks, performancecounter, perf

I need the "perf" utility to monitor the program on my Mac. I know linux comes with it, but is it available on Mac?

I am working on a OSX 10.9 Mavericks and tried "port search" for perf or linux-tools, but I couldn't get any results.

Comment: The perf(1) is heavily dependent on Linux-specific code. Your best bet is probably to try out http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/ which should compile on Mavericks as well.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As @Sami Laine said in his comment, the Linux `perf` tool is dependent on Linux specific code. It relies on the [perf_event_open](http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/perf_event_open.html) system call which is not standardized.

Note: Maybe you could search how MacOSX users are using recent hardware performance counters.

Comment: @thirty, MacOSX users can access hardware performance counters via `Instruments` application. There is manual how to use them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13075880/196561

Answer (score 34):

## *Instruments* app

On macOS you can use the [*Instruments*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_(software)) application to profile your code.

I like to use the "Time Profiler" which will show you how much time your application is its various parts during execution. I haven't used perf myself, but from talks/videos that I've seen this seems to be the most common use.

To use the "Time Profiler":

1. Run **Instruments**, select **Time Profiler**
2. At the top left, select your target (executable).
3. Hit the Record button on the top left and let it run for a little
   while.
4. Pause or Stop the execution and drill down on your calls in the main
   window.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can it profile for any hardware events other than time?  e.g. cache misses or branch mispredicts?

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed - how about basic branch prediction stats?!

Comment: @ATV: [osgx commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200704/install-perf-on-mac/45624891#comment35726412_23323081) that Instruments can indeed access HW performance counters, linking [Is there anyway to read performance counters on OS X Mountain Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13075880)  .  I don't have a Mac and have never used it, but osgx has posted a lot of `perf` answers so I suspect they know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 18):

On OSX you can use `sample` together with `filtercalltree`.

Both have useful help text if you run them without commands, but an example invocation to sample process id 1234 for the default 10 seconds at 1ms resolution would be something like:

```
sample 1234 -f output.prof
filtercalltree output.prof
```

Once you've generated your call graph, [FlameGraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) is another great tool for visualizing it, and it supports `sample` call graphs via the `stackcollpase-sample.awk` script.

Comment: How exactly one can do that?

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Do you know any way to collapse traces from multiple threads? Instruments.app can do this (when it works), but looks like filtercalltree cannot?

Comment: ```
sample 1234 -f output.prof
filtercalltree output.prof
./stackcollapse-sample.awk output.prof > out.folded
./flamegraph.pl out.folded > kernel.svg
```
should get you a flamegraph image.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Google Perf Tool

If you dont have brew installed:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

If you have brew installed:

```
brew install gperftools
```

Reference: https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools

Comment: I think gperftools only does time profiling, not HW performance events like branch mispredicts or cache misses.

Comment: A big caveat here: gperftools seems to require relinking the program being profiled.