# How can I measure cache misses on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, caching, profiling, cpu, cpu-cache

I've tried googling around, but only found KCachegrind, which depends on Valgrind, which doesn't work on OS X 10.10 Yosemite. I also looked around in Instruments, but couldn't find anything.

Is there a tool that can measure cache misses on OS X Yosemite? I'm basically looking for an alternative to the Linux' `perf` tool.

Comment: You used to be able to do this with Shark back in the old days, but it seems that it's still possible in Instruments, although setting up the performance registers is fiddly - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075113/is-there-anyway-to-read-performance-counters-on-os-x-mountain-lion

Comment: @PaulR I've tried to follow that in Instruments 6.1 but PM Events window, and basically after adding the Counters the described tutorial no longer applies :\

Comment: It should still be possible, but performance registers vary from CPU to CPU. You might want to check out the Mac version of [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com) - it's similar to Shark, the precursor to Instruments, which Instruments still hasn't caught up with in some regards. It's free now too!

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for the tip! I just tried to install Zoom, but it seems only 10.9 is supported, it doesn't seem to work on Yosemite :(

Comment: Oh, that's a shame - try emailing them and see if they plan to support Yosemite - I've found them very responsive in the past.